# How to read from video url or from usb camera using videoflow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, videoflow

In the [Videoflow](https://github.com/videoflow/videoflow) python library there are [examples](https://github.com/videoflow/videoflow/blob/master/examples/object_detector.py) on how to read from a video file, but how can I read video from the usb device in the computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just added into it.  You can do something like this. Just be sure to set the device id of your camera properly in the code.

```
import videoflow
import videoflow.core.flow as flow
from videoflow.core.constants import REALTIME
from videoflow.producers import VideoDeviceReader
from videoflow.consumers import VideofileWriter

class FrameIndexSplitter(videoflow.core.node.ProcessorNode):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FrameIndexSplitter, self).__init__()

    def process(self, data):
        index, frame = data
        return frame

def main():
    output_file = "output.avi"
    device_id = 0
    reader = VideoDeviceReader(device_id)
    frame = FrameIndexSplitter()(reader)
    writer = VideofileWriter(output_file, fps = 30)(frame)
    fl = flow.Flow([reader], [writer], flow_type = REALTIME)
    fl.run()
    fl.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```